# Downloading Gradle in Docker Container

Tags: docker, jenkins, gradle

I have a docker container which acts as a JenkinsSlave. It downloads the gradle version defined in the gradle-wrapper.properties via distributionUrl. In my case it's

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip

Now starting yesterday evening it stopped working. When I bash into the container and do a manual wget on https://services.gradle.org/... it doesn't work. It says "Unknown host services.gradle.org". When I do it without https - so just http://services.gradle.org it works fine.

Does anybody know which might be the root cause of this?

Comment: Maybe it was a temporary hickup, does this still happen? Do you maybe need some proxy that you didn't need until yesterday?

Comment: Ok... what did you do? :D Just started it again and now it works o.O.

Comment: I did nothing, I'm not related to Gradle except by being a user. :-)

Comment: hehe ok. Well thank you for your help anyway :)